# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_result() on boolean in --- line22

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","swap"); //connect to database
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_errno()); //return error is 
connect fail
}
?>

<?php
$user= $_POST['iuser'];
$name= $_POST['iname'];
$pwd = $_POST['ipwd'];
$cont= $_POST['icont'];
$userid = $_POST['uid'];

$updateuser=$con->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = '$user', password = 
'$pwd', email = '$mail', contact = '$cont' WHERE userID ='" .$userid. "'");    
$updateuser->bind_result($user, $pwd, $name, $add, $mail, $cont, $cardno);
$updateuser->execute();`
```

i have checked against many other questions but cant seem to find any errors. any help?

Comment: The $con->prepare failed and returns false to `$updateuser` - because of one `,` to much. Check `$con->error`!

Comment: Few issues, your mixing OOP and procedural mysqli functions and your still open to SQLi.

Comment: @jeff sorry, that was my typo when posting.

Answer (score 0):

There's more parameter than needed on your bind_result. Just give the parameter you need and use ? instead of param name (not sure about it but I use it like that) :

```
$updateuser=$con->prepare("UPDATE users SET username = ?, password = 
?, email = ?, contact = ?, WHERE userID = ?");    
$updateuser->bind_result($user, $pwd, $mail, $cont, $cardno);
```

Something like it work for me. (check if each param type check with DB column type)